# Where do you create the ini file? (Uwsgi)

Tags: uwsgi, ubuntu-20.04, apache2.4, django-4.0

my reference: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/

my project name:
'mysite'

my directories:
[image]

I create 'uwsgi.ini'.
[image]

then, I written in ini file.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/var/www/html/portfolio/mysite
module=mysite.wsgi:application
master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/yourproject.log
single-interpreter=True
```

then, I command 'service apache2 restart'

I command this 'uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini'

```
# uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
# open("/var/log/uwsgi/yourproject.log"): No such file or directory [core/logging.c line 288]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### reference(japanese)

[Ubuntu server fails](https://qiita.com/YoshitakaOkada/items/d1e14776040e64cd1434#ubuntu%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A7%E9%9A%9C%E5%AE%B3%E3%81%8C%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B)

```
(console)
# pip3 install uwsgi
  Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Successfully installed uwsgi-2.0.20
# mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi/vassals
# cd /etc/uwsgi/vassals
# source /var/www/html/venv/bin/activate

# vi uwsgi.ini
```

```
(uwsgi.ini(new))
[uwsgi]
chdir=/var/www/html/portfolio/mysite
module=mysite.wsgi:application
master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
single-interpreter=True
```

```
(console)
# adduser --group uwsgi-data
# adduser --home /etc/uwsgi --no-create-home --shell /sbin/nologin --ingroup uwsgi-data --disabled-login uwsgi-data
  Adding user `uwsgi-data' ...
  Adding new user `uwsgi-data' (1001) with group `uwsgi-data' ...
  Not creating home directory `/etc/uwsgi'.
  Changing the user information for uwsgi-data
  Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the 
  default
        Full Name []:  # Empty and OK
        Room Number []:
        Work Phone []:
        Home Phone []:
        Other []:
  Is the information correct? [Y/n] Y
```

```
(console)
# chown -R uwsgi-data:uwsgi-data /etc/uwsgi
# mkdir /var/log/uwsgi
# chown -R uwsgi-data:uwsgi-data /var/log/uwsgi
# vi /etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service
```

```
(emperor.uwsgi.service)
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.service

[Service]
# Find the configuration file that exists in "/etc/uwsgi/vassals" and start the uWSGI daemon.
ExecStart=/var/www/html/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
(console)
# chmod 755 /etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service
# vi /etc/uwsgi/vassals/emperor.ini
```

```
(emperor.ini)
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
uid = uwsgi-data
gid = uwsgi-data
```

```
(console)
# systemctl start emperor.uwsgi.service
# systemctl status emperor.uwsgi.service
  ● emperor.uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running)

# service apache2 restart
```